# Is the concept of a Point3 class, separate from a Vec3 class, unpythonic?

Tags: python, math

I'm writing some 3D math classes for Python. I'd like to make a Point3 class that is separate from Vec3 in the following respects:

> Point3 - Point3 = Vec3
>   Point3 + Vec3 = Point3

Otherwise, all operations on Vec3 you can perform on Point3. The motivation for this is to separate the mathematical concept of a point from a vector, hopefully leading to clearer type separation and an easier to understand API.

However, with Python's duck typing and the common practice of expecting a certain interface regardless of type, is it better just to use a Vec3? Is it more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems superfluous.  If you think about it, a point in cartesian space is entirely equivalent to a bound vector which begins at the origin.  Sounds like you could be making a lot of work for yourself for nothing.

Comment: *"a point is just a vector which conceptually begins at the origin of a cartesian space."* This eludes to an important fact, but isn't mathematically true.

Comment: All vectors have an origin, and a point can be on any manifold. Perhaps one could say that points are special cases of vectors that represent positions rather than any other sort of multidimensional quality? I don't see what difference is being alluded to here.

Comment: @Mike Graham: These (Vec3) can't represent arbitrary Euclidean vectors.  They are (more specifically) bound vectors on a cartesian space: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#In_Cartesian_space.  I will edit to be more correct.

Comment: @Devin, As datatypes, they support different operations. For example, the sum of two vectors is an important operation, but the sum of two points is not a valid operation.

Comment: @Mike Graham: According to OP, Point3 is a proposed type such that "all operations on Vec3 you can perform on Point3."

Comment: OP's suggestion probably doesn't make sense, then. Math-wise.

Comment: When I wrote that, I was referring to operations like Point3 * Vec3, where you want to scale. Anyway, it's nice to be able to do Mat4 * Point3 and Mat4 * Vec3 and get the correct result for both cases. (The former translates to Point3 = Mat4 * Vec4(Point3, 1) and the latter to Vec3 = Mat4 * Vec4(Vec3, 0) per homogeneous coordinates).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is particularly unpythonic.  It's not too unusual to distinguish types when they have the same domain, but when one has a particular frame of reference, such as a time zone,  Since a point is the sum of a vector and the origin, it's reasonable to encode that in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your argument.  I, too, have always struggled with classes for points.  In my experience it's better (although I guess perhaps not "more pythonic") to take a more functional approach and write your API in terms of functions that takes lists/tuples.

The main objection to this, I think, is that you probably want a compact way of writing simple algebraic operations (sums *etc.*),  but for that I would suggest using numpy.  Not only does numpy support element-wise addition, but it gives you efficiency where you are likely to need it in the future, with matrix operations and the like.

At the same time, while you say that you want a clean API, the differences you are adding to the API will be invisible, except in the documentation.  And really, an invisible API is not that useful.

I know this is nothing like what you were originally asking, but I suspect it is the best design in the long term (*i.e.* as your library grows and you want to support more ambitious transformations of points, batch processing, *etc.*, *etc.*).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is poor design, as adding or subtracting two points has no conceptual meaning.

You can, however, add a vector to a point (obtaining a point) or add two vectors (obtaining a vector), so it sounds like you are just confusing points with vectors.

A point is not a vector, but it *can* be implemented in terms of one.  In programming, we model *"implemented-in-terms-of"* relationships using composition - the `Point` class will contain a single private `Vector` instance, and use it to handle the logic of whatever methods it exposes.

In fact, because a `Vector` can already do all the same things a `Point` can (plus more), you may want to consider not even bothering to make the distinction, and using only the `Vector` class, with no `Point` class at all.  Whether or not this is a good idea depends on what your API will be used for.